# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host and java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header;

Tags: java, rmi

I've been learning about RMI and I started with the Hello World program, which I got to work, and then began using other sample programs which all worked. (well there were errors, but I debugged them with the help of google/stackoverflow). and now I began writing my own project, which is basically a Traveling Salesman implementation that offloads the intense computation to a server.

Everything was working fine, when suddenly all my server RMI implementations broke. ie. when I run computeEngine from Eclipse as an RMI application (I use the RMI plugin), I get either the error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host
```

or the error:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException
```

I have 4-5 different RMI applications that were all working and then all of a sudden the "ComputeEngine.java" file which I run on the server started returning one of these 2 errors for every single one of my applications.

Note: since I am testing these applications, I use "localhost" as my server hostname. In otherwords, the server and the client are the same machine.

Things I have tried:

1. I have checked my etc/hosts/ file and found that 127.0.0.1 is set as localhost. I also created a new machine entitled "virtualmachine" and used my public IP address. Both did not work.
2. I have double and triple checked my server.policy and client.policy files, and both seem to be fine.
3. I have tried running the RMI application from terminal (instead of using the RMI plugin from eclipse) and I get the same errors
4. I quit all java processes and reran everything making sure I started the server first (other threads suggested that these errors come from running the client first)
5. I've portscanned myself and port 1099 (the default rmi port) says "LISTEN" when I run my server (even though the server is returning an exception).
6. I've tried changing java.rmi.server.hostname, but nothing has seemed to help so far.

I'm not understanding how I'm not getting connection to host when I am running both the server and client on the same computer.

I preemptively apologize from being sucky at RMI and Java and missing some likely obvious solution.

Should I include any source code from what I have been trying to run?

EDIT: Here is the stack trace:

```
ComputeEngine exception:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:227)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at engine.ComputeEngine.main(ComputeEngine.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:213)
    ... 3 more
```

Thank You!

EDIT 2:

I noticed that if I restarted the RMIregistry when I started the application (as in, I selected the option in the Eclipse RMI plugin that restarted the rmiregistry) I would get a ClassNotFoundError for a class that is in my 'codebase.jar'.

```
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: compute.Compute
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the logs of your "ComputeEnginejava" server app? is there any error?

Comment: @fmodos Are logs the same thing as console output? because there are no "blahblah.log" files produced. the console says "java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:java.io.EOFException" (I can't paste the full error thing because of the comment length restriction.) It's caused by a Java.io.eofexception, which I do not understand because I am not taking any file input, unless RMI somehow throws this exception somewhere.

Comment: ok, please edit your question and post this full strackstrace

Comment: check the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101787/java-rmi-client-access-denied it seems to be the same error that you are facing

Comment: Thank you! I ran the server with "-Djava.security.debug=access,failure" and now I'm getting a new error. "fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class". Hopefully this means the current error is not longer a problem. There appears to be a ton of info about this new error in other questions and on google, so I should be able to solve it. Thank you for the help!